# lubridate mismatched index class

Tags: r, lubridate

Before I start, I would like to state that I have seen the FAQ entry at https://tsibble.tidyverts.org/articles/faq.html, however I am still unable to get to a workable solution.

I am using the "Aggregates (Bars)" output from polygon.io (https://polygon.io/docs/get_v2_aggs_ticker__forexTicker__range__multiplier___timespan___from___to__anchor)

Due to licensing/copyright restrictions I am unable to post the data here, but if you go to the docs link above, they have a sample there (no login required).

Polygon.io provide timestamp as follows:

> t integer The Unix Msec timestamp for the start of the aggregate
> window.

My attempt so far looks like this :

```
library(fpp3)
library(fable.prophet)
library(jsonlite)
library(curl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

myURL <-  # *N.B. For sample data please see doc link in SO question*
myData <- fromJSON(myURL)
myData$ticker

myData$results

parse1 <- myData$results %>% select(t,c) %>% 
  mutate(dt = as_datetime(t/1000),.keep="unused",.before=1)

print(head(parse1))

parse2 <- as_tsibble(parse1,index=dt)
```

However this yields:

```
Error: Can't obtain the interval due to the mismatched index class.
```

Comment: akrun, the link above has "Response Object" on on the right hand side which provides sample data. I do not want to risk copyright issues by copy/pasting from there to here.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I will edit that out completely and put a note there instead.

Comment: I think the issue I face is the duplicate time stamps after the conversion with `as_datetime`

Comment: ooops !!! My bad ... just checked my original code, I posted the wrong API, its this one : https://polygon.io/docs/get_v2_aggs_ticker__forexTicker__range__multiplier___timespan___from___to__anchor (will update the queetion)

Comment: Not sure how ?  The timestamps on their docs is 1590984000000 and 1591070400000 (so divide by 1000 and convert to datetime and its June 1 and June 2 ?)

Comment: With your new link.  I get only a single row from `parse1` `str(parse1)
'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dt: POSIXct, format: "2020-10-14"
 $ c : num 1.17`

Comment: Can you share the date range you used

Comment: My query URL (with API key removed is) is : "https://api.polygon.io/v2/aggs/ticker/C:EURUSD/range/1/day/2021-01-01/2021-06-18?unadjusted=true&sort=asc&limit=50000&apiKey=

Comment: If I do `print (parse1)`  it looks like this `1   2021-01-03 redacted` (have redacted the c column)

Comment: I updated the post with the reason why it is failing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the `regular` interval of `Datetime` column 'dt'.  We can convert it to `Date` class with `as.Date` and it works

```
library(dplyr)
library(tsibble)
parse1 %>%
      mutate(dt = as.Date(dt)) %>%
       as_tsibble(index = dt)
```

-output

```
# A tsibble: 120 x 2 [1D]
   dt             c
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2021-01-03  1.22
 2 2021-01-04  1.23
 3 2021-01-05  1.23
 4 2021-01-06  1.23
 5 2021-01-07  1.23
 6 2021-01-08  1.22
 7 2021-01-09  1.22
 8 2021-01-10  1.22
 9 2021-01-11  1.22
10 2021-01-12  1.22
# … with 110 more rows
```

---

Was able to replicate the same error in the OP's post

```
as_tsibble(parse1,index=dt)
Error: Can't obtain the interval due to the mismatched index class.
ℹ Please see `vignette("FAQ")` for details.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The issue is with the piece of code in `as_tsibble`

```
...
  if (unknown_interval(interval) && (nrows > vec_size(key_data))) {
    abort(c(
      "Can't obtain the interval due to the mismatched index class.",
      i = "Please see `vignette(\"FAQ\")` for details."
    ))
  }
...
```

There is an argument to specify if the `interval` is `regular` or not.  By default, it is `TRUE`.  Here, the interval is not regular.  So, we need

```
as_tsibble(parse1,index=dt)
Error: Can't obtain the interval due to the mismatched index class.
ℹ Please see `vignette("FAQ")` for details.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Thus, change the `regular` to `FALSE`

```
as_tsibble(parse1,index=dt, regular = FALSE)
# A tsibble: 120 x 2 [!] <GMT>
   dt                      c
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2021-01-03 00:00:00  1.22
 2 2021-01-04 00:00:00  1.23
 3 2021-01-05 00:00:00  1.23
 4 2021-01-06 00:00:00  1.23
 5 2021-01-07 00:00:00  1.23
 6 2021-01-08 00:00:00  1.22
 7 2021-01-09 00:00:00  1.22
 8 2021-01-10 00:00:00  1.22
 9 2021-01-11 00:00:00  1.22
10 2021-01-12 00:00:00  1.22
# … with 110 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I am just testing this out, bear with me. Its interesting because the FAQ I linked to seems to imply `POSIXct` is compatible but evidently it is not.

Comment: @LittleCode It would be compatible, but issue is that you are creating timestamp based on some calculation and there may be cases where the time will be having clash i.e. some case of daylight saving etc

Comment: Its only because the API provides timestamp in milliseconds ?  So I thought I have to divide by 1000 in order to get epoch seconds ? Or can I work directly from milliseconds ?

Comment: @LittleCode You may have to check the conversion formula.

Comment: awesome find on `regular=FALSE`. Thank you !